# How to fix fragment transaction not showing view unless app enters and returns from background?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Currently I am trying to add a new fragment on top of an existing fragment when a RecyclerView item is clicked. The behavior is not as expected. As shown in the below video. The fragment transaction works on the first try but once I leave the fragment and return (via the bottom bar) or scroll to the bottom of the list (which triggers pagination) the transaction no longer makes the desired fragment visible when item clicked.

However if I use the device menu button and bring the app back into the foreground, the correct fragment loads becomes visible.

Another odd behavior is that once the transaction seems to no longer work if I switch tabs using the bottom bar all fragments are replaced with blank screens. This is also fixed by the above method using the device menu button.

https://youtu.be/pYfdO5UB2Zc

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar" />

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
    app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/blue"
    app:bb_titleTextAppearance="@style/BottomBarText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity.java

```
private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
final Fragment mJobsFragment = JobsFragment.newInstance();
final Fragment mCalendarFragment = CalendarFragment.newInstance();
final Fragment mFeedFragment = FeedFragment.newInstance();
final Fragment mSettingsFragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance();
```

The addFragments() and setBottomBarTabSelectListener() are both called in the onCreate of the activity.

```
void addFragments () {
    mFragmentTransaction = 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_container, mSettingsFragment, 
mSettingsFragment.getTag());
    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_container, mFeedFragment, 
mFeedFragment.getTag());
    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_container, mCalendarFragment, 
mCalendarFragment.getTag());
    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_container, mJobsFragment, 
mJobsFragment.getTag());
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public void setBottomBarTabSelectListener(){
    mBottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {

            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            if(tabId == R.id.tab_jobs){
                selectedFragment = mJobsFragment;
            }
            else if(tabId == R.id.tab_calendar){
                selectedFragment = mCalendarFragment;
            }
            else if(tabId == R.id.tab_feed){
                selectedFragment = mFeedFragment;
            }
            else if(tabId == R.id.tab_settings){
                selectedFragment = mSettingsFragment;
            }

            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.view_container, selectedFragment);
            mFragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

This is called when a list item is clicked.

```
public void openJobDetails(){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_container ,JobDetailFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I have tested the item clicking and they are functioning properly. So there must be something with the Fragments and the Transaction that I am missing.

Comment: do you have a similar behavior when you press back and then reopen the app?

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
private jobDetailFragment = JobDetailFragment.newInstance();
public void openJobDetails(){ 
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
    fragmentTransaction.executePendingTransactions();
    if(jobDetailFragment.isAdded()){
        fragmentTransaction.show(jobDetailFragment);
    } else {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_container, jobDetailFragment);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); 
    fragmentTransaction.commit(); 
}
```

I think it's better add fragment once and use hide/show to switch fragment, use isAdded() to check add status, I mean for the four bottom tabs .And maybe start a new activity for jobDetail is a better way~

And you should do something to avoid Activity State Loss. See this: https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: This seemed to fix the issue. I used hide/show for the bottom bar fragments and created a parent activity for JobDetail.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem and fixed it by re-adding fragments in `onResume()`

```
 protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(tag,"onResume");
        addFragments ();
     }
```